# Как поставить точку на место, где находится пользователь и приблизить туда карту яндекс mapkit java

Tags: java, android, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

вот код моей активити, но я почему то не вижу точек

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserLocationObjectListener  {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private final String MAPKIT_API_KEY = "бла-бла-бла";
    private final Point TARGET_LOCATION = new Point(59.945933, 30.320045);

    private MapView mapView;
    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private UserLocationLayer userLocationLayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

        peremissionInternet();
        requestLocationPermission();

        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(MAPKIT_API_KEY);
        MapKitFactory.initialize(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.getMap().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(new Point(0, 0), 14, 0, 0));



        MapKit mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance();
        mapKit.resetLocationManagerToDefault();

        userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapView.getMapWindow());
        userLocationLayer.setVisible(true);
        userLocationLayer.setHeadingEnabled(true);
        userLocationLayer.setObjectListener((UserLocationObjectListener) this);



        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mapView.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void peremissionInternet(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.INTERNET")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.INTERNET"},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectAdded(UserLocationView userLocationView) {
        userLocationLayer.setAnchor(
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.5)),
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.83)));

        userLocationView.getArrow().setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(
                this, R.drawable.geolocation));

        CompositeIcon pinIcon = userLocationView.getPin().useCompositeIcon();

        pinIcon.setIcon(
                "icon",
                ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.geolocation),
                new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0f, 0f))
                        .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                        .setZIndex(0f)
                        .setScale(1f)
        );

        pinIcon.setIcon(
                "pin",
                ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.geolocation),
                new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f))
                        .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                        .setZIndex(1f)
                        .setScale(0.5f)
        );

        userLocationView.getAccuracyCircle().setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectRemoved(UserLocationView view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectUpdated(UserLocationView view, ObjectEvent event) {
    }

}
```

при этом в логах я вижу кучу варнингов, которые, никак не влияю на работоспособность карт

я дурак или лыжи не едут, прошу помочь новичку

Answer (score 1):

Для тех, кто тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, немного поразмыслив, переписав код, я понял, что виновато боттом меню, точнее не само меню, а отрисовка дравер лайоута, потом, поняв, что у меня есть несколько setContentView, при этом один находился под стартом фабрики, а другой над, решил переместить их в один блок, по мануалу в яндекс мап кит, и о чудо, оно заработало. Код прикреплю ниже

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserLocationObjectListener  {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private final String MAPKIT_API_KEY = "бла-бла-бла";
    private final Point TARGET_LOCATION = new Point(59.945933, 30.320045);

    private MapView mapView;
    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private UserLocationLayer userLocationLayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

        peremissionInternet();
        requestLocationPermission();

        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(MAPKIT_API_KEY);
        MapKitFactory.initialize(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.getMap().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(new Point(0, 0), 14, 0, 0));

        MapKit mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance();
        userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapView.getMapWindow());
        userLocationLayer.setVisible(true);
        userLocationLayer.setHeadingEnabled(true);

        userLocationLayer.setObjectListener(this);



        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mapView.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void peremissionInternet(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                "android.permission.INTERNET")
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{"android.permission.INTERNET"},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectAdded(UserLocationView userLocationView) {
        userLocationLayer.setAnchor(
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.5)),
                new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float)(mapView.getHeight() * 0.83)));

        userLocationView.getArrow().setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(
                this, R.drawable.geolocation));

        CompositeIcon pinIcon = userLocationView.getPin().useCompositeIcon();

        pinIcon.setIcon(
                "icon",
                ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.geolocation),
                new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0f, 0f))
                        .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                        .setZIndex(0f)
                        .setScale(1f)
        );

        pinIcon.setIcon(
                "pin",
                ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.geolocation),
                new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f))
                        .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                        .setZIndex(1f)
                        .setScale(0.5f)
        );

        userLocationView.getAccuracyCircle().setFillColor(Color.BLUE & 0x99ffffff);
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectRemoved(UserLocationView view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onObjectUpdated(UserLocationView view, ObjectEvent event) {
    }
}
```